# Export NFS to multiple networks in FreeBSD (FreeNAS)

Tags: freebsd, nfs, truenas

I'm trying to export a share to multiple networks using the following in the /etc/exports file:

```
/mnt/tank/xen_nfs -alldirs -mapall=root:wheel -network 10.1.1.20 10.1.1.45 10.1.1.105
```

but whenever I try to connect from those three servers, I get a Permissions problem.  If I just have any one of the networks by itself, it works fine.
This is running FreeNAS 8.0RC5 (FreeBSD 8.2).  I've also tried specifying the networks with a /30 designation, but same problem.

Comment: .45 and .105 aren't /30 network IDs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to export to those three as /30 networks, you need to specify each network as a network..

```
/mnt/tank/xen_nfs -alldirs -mapall=root:wheel -network 10.1.1.20/30 
/mnt/tank/xen_nfs -alldirs -mapall=root:wheel -network 10.1.1.44/30 
/mnt/tank/xen_nfs -alldirs -mapall=root:wheel -network 10.1.1.104/30
```

If you don't specify that the following IP is a network, it will think it is a single host's IP.

You can quickly see what the server thinks should be able to access the mount with `showmount -e`

Comment: That works.  I did not realize you could specify the same mount point multiple times.  Thanks